# How to make an Onboarding screen that has a dissolve effect when changing pages in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview

I'm trying to make an Onboarding/Walkthrough screen similar to Audible's current one using UIScrollview. Their onboarding screen uses a dissolve in and out effect when the user is scrolling to the next page. My code isn't of good quality, and I haven't been able to fix content sizing yet, but I think it'd be better if I had something to show for:

```
lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {

    let sv = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))

    sv.delegate = self
    sv.isPagingEnabled = true
    sv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    sv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sv.backgroundColor = nil


    return sv

}()


lazy var scrollImageView: UIImageView = {

    let siv = UIImageView()
    siv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    siv.frame = self.view.bounds
    siv.clipsToBounds = true

    return siv


}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    for  i in stride(from: 0, to: imagelist.count, by: 1) {
        var frame = CGRect.zero
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(i)
        frame.origin.y = 0
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size
        let myImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: imagelist[i])!
        scrollImageView.image = myImage



        scrollView.addSubview(scrollImageView)
    }


    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(imagelist.count), height: self.view.frame.height)

}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)


}
```